# If a person is court ordered to pay child support in the state of Ohio does that person have the right to claim said children on taxes

Tags: tax-law

Who has the right to claim children. On federal taxes in Ohio?

Comment: Probably not, does that person have 50/50 custody? How many children? What does the custody agreement say?

Answer (score 3):

For US federal purposes, the rule is that the person who provided 50% or more of the support for a child can claim that child as a dependent, whoever has custody, unless there is an agreement to the contrary. Most states follow this rule. But a custody agreement can provide that one party or the other can make the tax claim. If both parties claim the same person as a dependent, the IRS will be annoyed.